# preg_match_all question (how to limit scope without a seperate preg_match call)

Tags: php, regex

I have some data similar to this:

```
aaa1|aaa2|ZZZ|aaa3|aaa4|aaa5|ZZZ|aaa6|aaa7
```

I want to match all "aaa[0-9]" BETWEEN "ZZZ" (not the ones outside).

So I have some PHP code:

```
    $string = "aaa1aaa2zzzzaaa3aaa4aaa5zzzzaaa6aaa7";

    preg_match_all("/zzzz.*(aaa[0-9]).*zzzz/", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    print_r($matches);
```

But it only outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => zzzzaaa3aaa4aaa5zzzz
            [1] => aaa5
        )

)
```

I want "aaa3", "aaa4" in addition to "aaa5".

Is there a way to do this with 1 call to `preg_match_all()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the string occurs before one delimiter string (zzzz) but not before two delimiter strings:

```
$string = "aaa1aaa2zzzzaaa3aaa4aaa5zzzzaaa6aaa7";

preg_match_all("/aaa[0-9](?=.*?zzzz)(?!(?>.*?zzzz).*?zzzz)/", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with a single call.  You'll need to do one call to pull out the contents between your delimiters (zzzz) and then another call to pull out all the matching pairs.

```
if (preg_match('/zzzz(.*?)zzzz/', $string, $matches)) {
    preg_match_all('/(aaa\d)/', $matches[1], $newmatches);
    print_r($newmatches);
} else {
    echo "No match";
}
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately 1 call is the only option I have. It is a 3rd party system that I know calls preg_match_all but I cannot change the code, only feed in a rule.